# Empty datagridview when passed from anothe form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to pass my `datagridview` data in first form to another `datagridview` in second form. However, when I load the second form, the `datagridview` is empty. Below is my code:

**First Form**

```
public Newdatagridd(List<Newclass> records)
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        Records = records;

        foreach (var r in Records)
        {
            String[] row = { r.column1, r.column2, r.column3, r.column4};
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    //copy data to second form
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
        Newdatagrid ndg = new Newdatagrid(dataGridView1.DataSource);
        ndg.Show();
    }
```

**Second Form**

```
public Newdatagrid(object dataSource)
    {          
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: You did not use a DataSource.  You added rows directly to the control, so there will be nothing in the `DataSource` you pass

Comment: How do I use `DataSource`? Bcs my code do not have any `databases`

Answer (score 0):

There is no data source for datagridView1 because you manually add rows here. 
You need to use something like this

```
  var source = new BindingSource();
  source.DataSource = Records;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

If you are using VS, then there is a simple way to select the datasource from the object in design mode: Select right top coner DataGrid, than select Chose DataSource, select in Combo "Add Project data source" -> Object -> Next and than chose your object class. After it - use code before for binding